# Using nestjs with apollo-server version 2

Tags: typescript, apollo-server, nestjs

I started to learn nestjs and tried [this example](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/tree/master/sample/12-graphql-apollo) with graphql.

But the example was written for apollo-server version 1 and now I have problems to get it working with apollo-server version 2.
Currently it is not clear to me how to get the apollo-server version 2 into the [consumer](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/e39c9d920d75457695a32bc39745c88bbd244bd7/sample/12-graphql-apollo/src/app.module.ts#L27):

```
consumer
  .apply(
    graphiqlExpress({
      endpointURL: '/graphql',
      subscriptionsEndpoint: `ws://localhost:3001/subscriptions`,
    }),
  )
  .forRoutes('/graphiql')
  .apply(graphqlExpress(req => ({ schema, rootValue: req })))
  .forRoutes('/graphql');
```

Has someone please a tip how this nextjs example can be used with apollo-server version 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example has been updated already (+ensure to update your `@nestjs/graphql` to the latest version)